# building a stack of JSONP requests

Tags: javascript, dom, jsonp

i am building an auto suggest box with wikipedia api and **the problem is that the order of updates to `DOM` is based on the order of responses retrieved from the server whereas it should actually depend on the order of firing of `onkeyup` event.**
so if i m looking for `Lady Gaga` and i press `L` and then `a` .now if the response from the request where i am looking for `L` comes later than response for `La` then `DOM` is updated with response of L which should not happen because my most recent input is `La`.

Therefore on every `onkeyup` event a create a `Request` object that has the timestamp of when the request was created(`onkeyup` event fired) and store it a global array `requests` . also there is global variable `lastValidRequest` that stores the timestamp of the last `Request` object that actually modified `DOM`. In the callback function  i check whether a `Request` whose timestamp is less than `lastValidRequest` and discard those requests because they are old and newer `Request` than them has been sent. I have commented the code to my best to make every-thing easily understandable. The code looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var requests=new Array();  // array to hold requests

    var lastValidRequest=(new Date()).getTime(); // shows the time of the last request whose callback function was called

    function cb(data) // calls send method of Request object
    {
        requests[requests.length-1].send(data);  //this is where i m going wrong but i dont know wat to do here
    }

    function Request(url) //request constructor
    {
        this.time=(new Date()).getTime();  //time at which request was created
        this.url=url+"&callback=cb";
        this.node=document.createElement('script');
        this.node.src=this.url;
        this.ran=false;   // indicates whether this request modified the div element's contents,just used for making debuuging easy
        return this;
    };

    Request.prototype.send=function(data) {
        if (this.time < lastValidRequest) // check if a newer request has been made
        {
            this.node.parentNode.removeChild(this.node); // cancel the request
            //this.node=null;
        }
        else                               // this is the newest request
        {
            lastValidRequest=this.time; //set lastValidRequest to time of this request
            this.ran=true;    
            var str="";
            for(var i=0;i<data[1].length;i++)
                str=str+data[1][i]+"</br>";
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=str;
            this.node.parentNode.removeChild(this.node);
        }
    };


    window.onload=function()
    {
        textbox=document.getElementById('search');
        textbox.onkeyup=function() {
            var text=textbox.value;     // text is the query for the GET request
            if(text=="")
            {
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
            var url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" +text + "&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json";
            requests.push(new Request(url)); // create a new request and add it to the end of the array
            document.body.appendChild(requests[requests.length-1].node);
        }
    }
</script>
```

there is `pastebin` link of this code [here](http://pastebin.com/K0thzNBB)

---

**UPDATE**

i have figured out how to get away with the `wikipedia api` because when it returns a response for a search it also returns the search query. for example if i search for `gaga` then the `JSON`response returned is this

```
["gaga",["GaGa","GAGA","Gagarin's Start","Gagauz people","Gagauzia","Gaga","Gagaku","Gagauz language","Gagarin","Gagan Narang"]]
```

now i can easily figure out which response belongs to which request. So i can do something like this to see if the response is for the most recent request

```
if (textbox.value==data[0])  //check if searchbox's value is same as JSON's first element
{
//update dom because response its for latest request
}
```

but the exact thing i am looking for is

**HOW DO I ASSOCIATE A REQUEST WITH A RESPONSE IN GENERAL?**

that is how do i decide which response belongs to which request (*am i over hypothesizing?*)

Comment: You explained what your code does, but it is not clear what the problem you are having is.  Does it work at all?  Incidentally, did you include all the code?  (I ask because I see no code relating to submitting the requests.)

Comment: @cheeken the request are submitted when the `script`element is added to the `dom`. the problem is that order of update of `div` is dependent on the order of receiving the responses from server where it should actually depend on the firing of `onkeyup` event

Comment: If you're doing enough of the *same* request to get this mixed up, you're probably hitting the server too often.

Comment: @Ryan Kinal i dont understand "enough of the same request to get this mixed up"

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to only allow one connection at a time by aborting the previous one.

Unfortunately, I didn't understand your code well enough to see how this is done, but with regular AJAX and jQuery, it would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var curr_request=null;

        $('#autosuggest').keyup(function(){

            // abort existing request
            if(curr_request)curr_request.abort();

            // do the request
            curr_request = $.getJSON(the_url,function(data){
                curr_request=null;
                // populate autosuggest with data
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:** Since you're dealing with JSONP, to "abort" a request, you would probably have to remove the script node from the document. Something like `document.body.removeChild(requests[requests.length-1].node);`
If so, you don't need to keep a stack as well, just keep track of the last one, as I did with `curr_request` in my example.

Comment: can you please point out what exactly you are not able to understand? i will edit my code accordingly

Comment: Mostly why you are keeping a whole stack of requests, including trivial things such as time. Also, **avoid** global variables like `textbox` by adding a `var` before it. Also, why have a whole object "Request" at all? If you rethink your process, you'll realize you only need one "request", hence no need for a stack.

Comment: i cannot `abort` the request by removing the node. even if i write `document.body.appendChild(script);var script=document.createElement("script");
document.body.removeChild(script);` the `dom` will be updated by the callback fuction. that is why in my code i attach the `script` element only when i detect that this is the latest query

Comment: That's a detail you should have specified before. First, try remove the src (replace it with a dummy value) and see if it works. If it doesn't, then a delayed stack is the way to go. But it is extremely inefficient and slow.

Comment: setting the src attribute to null or "" wont cancel the request. and yes there is more work being done here but it guarantees correctness